# Interchanging expecation and a monotone function

Tags: probability

Are there any theorems similar to Jensen's Inequality for monotone functions instead of convex functions? For example, if I know $EX \le EY$, can I say anything about $Ef(X)$ and $Ef(Y)$ given that I know $f$ is a nondecreasing function?

Comment: Jensen's inequality is about comparing $Ef(X)$ and $f(E X)$. I cannot see why you think your question is similar to Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are stochastically ordered, i.e. say $X\leq_{st.}Y$, then we have both $$\mathbb{E}(X)\leq \mathbb{E}Y\ \mbox{and}\ \mathbb{E}(f(X))\leq \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$$ where $f$ is a non-decreasing function.

Conversely, if for any non-decreasing function $f$ we have $$\mathbb{E}(f(X))\leq \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$$ then it follows that $X\leq_{st.}Y$ and consequently $\mathbb{E}(X)\leq \mathbb{E}(Y)$.

For more on stochastic ordering see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering).

Comment: When you say "if for *any* non-decreasing function..." I suspect it might be clearer if you said *every*

Comment: @Henry, I actually meant "every" by saying "any" :-). By the way, just for curiosity, is there any formal difference between these two words?

Comment: Samrat - I know that is what you meant, but to me *any* can either mean *every* or it can mean *at least one*, and the difference matters here.  

The first time I read your statement, I thought you were saying that if you could find any example of particular non-decreasing function with $\mathbb{E}(f(X))\leq \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$ then $X\leq_{st.}Y$ would follow.  That is not true, so I had to reread the statement.  It is not a major point.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, suppose $f(x)=x^2$:

Now suppose $X=0$ with probability $0.5$ and $X=2$ with probability $0.5$; and  $Y=0$ with probability $0.6$ and $Y=3$ with probability $0.4$. Then $E[X]=1 \lt 1.2 =E[Y]$ and $E[f(X)]=2 \lt 3.6 =E[f(Y)]$.

Compare this with $X=0$ with probability $0.5$ and $X=2$ with probability $0.5$; and  $Y=0$ with probability $0.2$ and $Y=1.5$ with probability $0.8$. Then $E[X]=1 \lt 1.2 =E[Y]$ again but $E[f(X)]=2 \gt 1.8 =E[f(Y)]$.